# providing WebSVN with repo authentication information

Tags: authentication, svn

I've set up several repos on a network resource that our team access via this format URL:

```
svn://IP-address/sitename
```

However, I am struggling to figure a way of enabling WebSVN to access the password protected directories of those repos (anon-access=none currently). I could remove the anon-access directive - but is there another way round this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that svnserve uses its own user database. I would recommend either use mod_svn with apache, which would allow you to share user databases, as authentication is done the same way by using http-auth.

Alternatively, svnserve over SSH could be used provided you used something like LDAP for your user accounts on the server and would require you to allow your users to log into the subversion server.

My preference would be to use the Apache module. I usually use that and back it with an LDAP database for authentication.

Comment: +1 for apache. We use it with LDAP authentication against our Active Directory, so it's one username/password for everything throughout the organisation